# Why do I get the Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT], even though I added a Header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, module

Hoi.
I am currently trying to create a simple Chat server with Express and Node.js
But in the Post Method I get every time this error when I try to read the file where all the chat messages are stored. The program should append the newest message to the file and then send them all to the client, but I don't think it does that at all.

I searched, and it said that the error appears when I don't say a header. So I added a header, but it still appears.

What could be the problem?

The browser doesn't even get anything. It gives me the HTTP Error 404.

PS: Don't mind the comments and the hois. They are my tries of fixing the error.
Even so don't give the Get Method much attention yet, I wanted to fix the Post first.

Server.js

```
const logger = require('./logger');
const fileFunc = require('./modeChat');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let hoi =(string='hoi')=>console.log(string)


let messageFile='../DataSave/message.txt';

//http.createServer(function (req, res) {
//res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
app.use((reg,res,next)=>{
    logger.log('You got a request:'+ reg.method)
    next();
});

app.get('/file/:fileName',(req,res)=>{
    let fileName = req.params.fileName;
    res.sendFile(fileName,{root: __dirname});
});

app.route('/chat?')
.get((req,res,next)=>{
    hoi("Not at all. ^^")
    (async ()=>{
        
        let chatObj = JSON.parse(chatObj = JSON.parse(fileFunc.readFile(messageFile)));
        
        res.write(JSON.stringify(chatObj));
        res.end();
    }
    )().catch(()=>{
        res.write("Nothing yet");
        res.end();
    })
    next();
})
.post((req,res,next)=>{
   
    let chatObj;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    (async ()=>{
        try{
            hoi("IT'S ME");
            //chatObj = JSON.parse(fileFunc.readFile(messageFile));
            //let data = await fileFunc.readFile(messageFile,"utf-8");
            hoi("I am here");
            hoi(fileFunc.readFile(messageFile));
            chatObj = JSON.parse(/*data*/await fileFunc.readFile(messageFile));
        } catch {
            hoi("Yes? ^^");
            chatObj = new fileFunc.ChatObj();
        }
       hoi("I will be beautiful!");
        fileFunc.addMessage(req,chatObj);
    
        fileFunc.writeDataSequential(messageFile,chatObj)

        res.status(200)
        res.send(JSON.stringify(chatObj));
        //res.end();
    }
    )().catch((err)=>hoi(err));
    next();
})
.options((req,res,next)=>{
    fileFunc.deleteFile(messageFile);

    res.status(200).send()
    next();
})

app.listen(8080, ()=> console.log('Online on Port 8080. Mwhahah!'));
```

modeChat.js

```
let fs = require('fs');
let url = require('url');

function ChatObj(){
    this.message=[];
}

function Message(someone,something){
    this.user= someone;
    this.message= something;
}

let readFile= async function(fileName){/*
    let data = await fs.promises.readFile(fileName,"utf-8");
    console.log(data);
    return data;*/
    return  fs.promises.readFile(fileName,"utf-8");
}
        
let addMessage=function(req,chatObj){
    let q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    let mes = new Message(q.query.user,q.query.message);
    chatObj.message.push(mes);
}
           
let writeDataSequential=function(fileName,chatObj){
    fs.promises.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(chatObj));
}            

let deleteFile =function(fileName){
    if(fs.existsSync(fileName)){
        fs.promises.unlink(fileName);
    }
}
module.exports = {
    Message,
    ChatObj,
    readFile,
    addMessage,
    writeDataSequential,
    deleteFile
}
```

The Terminal output:

```
Online on Port 8080. Mwhahah!
logger.js (2022-1-10 15:55:30 - 762): You got a request:POST
IT'S ME
I am here
Promise { <pending> }
I will be beautiful!
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\jusau\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\jusau\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at [The Paht]\MIB\Chat\ServerParts\WebServer.js:62:13 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

The WebServer.js:62:13 line is res.send(JSON.stringify(chatObj));

Comment: It looks like the server tries to modify the headers after it started sending the body at `WebServer.js:62:13`. Can you tell us which line it is?

Comment: @jabaa Just corrected the post. ^^

Comment: Why do you call `next` after you've sent a response? Doesn't that send a second response? Can you start the server in your debugger and set a breakpoint at the beginning of each handler? I guess you're calling multiple handlers per request.

Comment: @jabaa oh gosh! The Next was the problem! Thanks very much!